# process.getInputStream() return null on adb command

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to reboot to download but i am getting:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.InputStream java.lang.Process.getInputStream()' on a null object reference

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


   String[] s ={"adb", "reboot", "download"};
   Process p = null;
   try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

}
```

I tried to put the code into different thread.

Why `process.getInputStream()` return `null` on `adb` command ?

Comment: it's `p` the null, not `getInputStream()`

Answer (score 0):

try removing `Process p = null` , and implement it in the `try` body :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


   String[] s ={"adb", "reboot", "download"};
   try {
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

}
```

Comment: a little explanation is good btw, i see your code is 100% copy/paste from the question code itself ?!

Comment: i have make changes from the question .... i have removed Process p = null , and implemented in the try body

Comment: oh, that's what i mean u need to explain what your answer is **also** would not this code generate a compile error `unable to resolve variable p` ??

Comment: you cann't get to the 'p'